# Difference between this Bits class and Bitset

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a question on the differences between the [Bits](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Bits.html) class from the LibGDX library and the [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class in the standard Java library. Was the Bits class built to be faster in handling bitwise operations or more memory efficient?

Comment: Looks to be the same thing with a few more operations.  I would expect the underlying data structure to be identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Bits.java) is the source of that class. Here's the source of [`BitSet`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/BitSet.java). At a glance they're very similar; they're both backed by `long[]`s. I would not expect any particular improvement in performance. You can use whichever you'd prefer, though I'd err on the side of the JDK implementation as more standard.

It's somewhat odd that the class doesn't even mention the JDK's `BitSet` (such as a "This class performs better/worse than BitSet in such-and-such case") which makes me wonder if the implementors simply didn't look for such a class in the JDK before creating theirs.